# Where can I find all the selector xml attributes, include sub-attributes as well?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android, recently encounter selector xml, found that selector can contains "item", in "item" it can contains "shape", "gradient" and more! I try to search the documentation regarding to this but can't locate.

Anyone know where can I locate all the xml attributes related to Selector?

Answer (score 0):

please check this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: I have checked, seen like the doc is not completed, I saw an example, inside "item", we can have "shape", but in the doc, I cannot find this info. why?